# Verificação de informações repetidas em array

Tags: php

Tenho dois `arrays` como eu faria em `PHP` para retornar em um terceiro `array` apenas números que não estejam no primeiro e segundo `array`.

**Exemplo:**

Se eu tenho o número **1** e **2** no primeiro `array` meu terceiro `array` deve receber apenas **3** e **4**

```
$primeiro_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$segundo_array = ["1", "2"];
```

Esse terceiro `array` só vai receber números que não estejam repetidos entre o 
primeiro e segundo `array`

```
$terceiro_array = ["3", "4"];
```

Existe uma forma de fazer isso com `PHP`?

Comment: "apenas números que não estejam no primeiro e segundo array" isso ficou bastante confuso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php)

> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> `array_diff` — Computa as diferenças entre *arrays*
>
> ```
> array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ] ) : array
> ```
>
> Compara `array1` com um ou mais *arrays* e retorna os valores no `array1` que não estão presentes em nenhum dos outros arrays.

Exemplo:

```
$array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
$array2 = ['1', '2'];

$array3 = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($array3);
```

Saída

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php)

```
$primeiro_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$segundo_array = ["1", "2"];

$terceiro_array = array_diff($primeiro_array, $segundo_array);
```

dessa forma ele vai trazer o resultado esperado, mas, com a indexação atual, para melhorar isso pode fazer um [array_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php):

```
$terceiro_array = array_values(array_diff($primeiro_array, $segundo_array));
```

para que fique igual da pergunta.

[Resultado Exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/w36zW7)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php)
- [array_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score -4):

Existe uma função chamada "in_array" onde ele retorna se 'x' valor está presente no array em questão. Com uma estrutura de foreach/if/else você conseguiria este resultado que deseja de verificar seus números na array 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php