# Comparação de array em php

Tags: php

Tenho um `array` do tipo

```
array1(array(1,2,3,4,5), array(2,3,4,5,6));
```

e outro do tipo

```
array2(1,2,3,4,6);
```

Preciso comparar o array1 com o array2 e pegar a diferença entre eles, porém o array1 é um conjunto de arrays e não sei como fazer isso.

Usei a função `array_diff($array1, $array2);` que quando utilizado com arrays simples como é o caso do array2, retorna a diferença entre eles num array, seria ótimo se funcionasse com cada array do array1 comparando com o array2, porém li sobre a função e nada fala sobre comparar estes tipos de arrays.

Comment: você precisa então gerar um array com as diferenças entre as posições do array1?

Comment: Exato, cada posição do array1 ser comparada com o array2.

Comment: que diferença você quer especifique melhor, você quer saber quantos elementos há dentro de um array e quantos há no outro?

Comment: vc quer comparar o array2 com o array1 ou com a primeira array dentro do  array1?

Comment: A diferença dos elementos, por exemplo a primeira posição do array1 possui o 5 e o array2 não possui, já a segunda posição também possui o 5 e o array2 não. basicamente quero aprender a comparar cada posição do 1 com o 2. o dois é fixo, o que me complica é que o array1 é um array com vários outros arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar a função [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php):

```
$array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6]];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,6];

$diferencas = array_map(function ($array1) use ($array2) {
    return array_diff($array1, $array2);
}, $array1);
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 5
        )

)
```

Pois o número 5 é o único elemento que está em `$array1` e que não está em `$array2`.

Se não precisar manter a referência de `$array1` intacta, você pode utilizar [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk.php):

```
$array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6]];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,6];

array_walk($array1, function (&$array1, $index) use ($array2) {
  $array1 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
});
```

Em que `$array1` ficaria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 5
        )

)
```

Diferente da primeira opção, que cria um novo *array*, esta altera o *array* original por referência.

Comment: é exatamente isso! Eu sempre fico confuso se posso agradecer aqui na comunidade, mas de toda forma, obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa pegar cada posição e verificar com [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php) qual é a diferença do outro `array` e crie um novo `array` com essas diferenças, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

    $array1 = array(array(1,2,3), array(3,4,5));
    $array2 = array(3,4);

    $arrayfinal = array();

    foreach($array1 as $arr)
    {
        $arrayfinal[] = array_diff($arr, $array2);
    }

    print_r($arrayfinal);
```

Saída:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [2] => 5 ) )
```

outro link: [Verificação de informações repetidas em array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365510/verifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-repetidas-em-array/365518#365518)